# How to include CSS file in Symfony 2 and Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm playing around with **Symfony2**, and I have problems including **CSS** and **JS** files in **Twig** template.

I have a bundle named `Webs/HomeBundle` inside which I have `HomeController` with `indexAction` that renders a twig template file:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render("WebsHomeBundle:Home:index.html.twig");
}
```

So this is easy. Now what I want to do, is to include some CSS and JS files inside this Twig template. Template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The file I would like to include, `main.css` file is located in:

```
Webs/HomeController/Resources/public/css/main.css
```

So my question is basically, how the hell do I include simple CSS file inside Twig template?

I'm using Twig `asset()` function and it just doesn't hit the right CSS path. Also, I run this command in console:

```
app/console assets:install web
```

This created a new folder

```
/web/bundles/webshome/...
```

this is just linking to the

```
src/Webs/HomeController/Resources/public/
```

right?

## Questions

1. Where do you place your **asset** files, JS, CSS, and images? Is it OK to put them in `Bundle/Resources/public` folder? Is that the right location for them?
2. How do you include these **asset** files in your Twig template using asset function? If they are in public folder, how can I include them?
3. Should I configure something else?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You are doing everything right, except passing your bundle path to `asset()` function.

According to [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig) - in your example this should look like below:

```
{{ asset('bundles/webshome/css/main.css') }}
```

**Tip**: you also can call assets:install with `--symlink` key, so it will create symlinks in web folder. This is extremely useful when you often apply `js` or `css` changes (in this way your changes, applied to `src/YouBundle/Resources/public` will be immediately reflected in `web` folder without need to call `assets:install` again):

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

Also, if you wish to **add** some assets in your child template, you could call `parent()` method for the Twig block. In your case it would be like this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link href="{{ asset('bundles/webshome/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: app/console assets:install --watch will automatically regenerate assets as they change

Comment: @Radu yes but if you create symlinks you won't need the --watch

Answer (score 12):

And you can use %stylesheets% (assetic feature) tag:

```
{% stylesheets
    "@MainBundle/Resources/public/colorbox/colorbox.css"
    "%kerner.root_dir%/Resources/css/main.css"
%}
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

You can write path to css as parameter (%parameter_name%).

More about this variant: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are valid, but the [Official Symfony Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/master/best_practices/web-assets.html) guide suggests using the `web/` folder to store all assets, instead of different bundles.

> Scattering your web assets across tens of different bundles makes it
>   more difficult to manage them. Your designers' lives will be much
>   easier if all the application assets are in one location.
>
> Templates also benefit from centralizing your assets, because the
>   links are much more concise[...]

I'd add to this by suggesting that you only put micro-assets within micro-bundles, such as a few lines of styles only required for a button in a button bundle, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using **Silex** add the **Symfony Asset** as a dependency:

```
composer require symfony/asset
```

Then you may register **Asset Service Provider**:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\AssetServiceProvider(), array(
    'assets.version' => 'v1',
    'assets.version_format' => '%s?version=%s',
    'assets.named_packages' => array(
        'css' => array(
            'version' => 'css2',
            'base_path' => __DIR__.'/../public_html/resources/css'
        ),
        'images' => array(
            'base_urls' => array(
                'https://img.example.com'
            )
        ),
    ),
));
```

Then in your **Twig** template file in head section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('style.css') }}" />
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As per documentation, you should also add twig-bridge (`composer require symfony/twig-bridge`)