# How to use short assets path in Twig Template for Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I found how to reference an asset file on a Twig template here: [How to include CSS file in Symfony 2 and Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165485/how-to-include-css-file-in-symfony-2-and-twig)

It says I should include the bundle folder in the path like this example: `{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/css/main.css') }}`

This solution is not reliable for me because I have many website templates with extensive asset file references (JS, CSS, Images) that I need to convert into Twig template and its hard for me to replace all asset paths with a full path like I mentioned in the example. At least it can be easier if I can use it like this: `{{ asset('css/main.css') }}`

Can anyone please help me in this issue ? Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The news best practices recommended by Symfony are now to regroup the assets of your app in the web/ folder, you loose a bit of the re usability of your code but you get rid of a lot of suffering in your asset management.

This way you **will** be "able" (without thinking you are doing some dirty developement ;) ) to store your CSS in the `web/css/` folder you made and then call them with

```
{{ asset('css/main.css') }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html

> "Best Practice :
>
> Store your assets in the web/ directory."

Answer (score 1):

You can include all css in a folder like this:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/main/js/lightbox/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but I had to put all my resources under /web folder instead, because with the following method I should include all CSS and JS files I have, thing I shouldn't do