# How can I use a core html web template to view in Symfony framework with route?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I tried it many time, but not able to execute it.

Already I have a static website and it not working if I change its extension to twig format, like index.html to index.html.twig.(css and javascript not working if I use twig)

Comment: sorry for bad english

Comment: Is this template called from php action (rendered by Symfony)?

Comment: public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('AcmeCmsadminBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    
}

Comment: And what do You mean by "not working"? Do You see any error message (when running it in dev environment)?

Comment: already i have a html static web pages and if i use it with symfony 'VIEW' then its css and javascript not working

Comment: where do you put your css/javascript ? How do you add the assets inside your template? Do you access your application using `http://<host>/app_dev.php/` or what url are you using? Please add that information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include css and js files the easiest (but not recommended) way is to put css and js files inside /web/ directory and in template file include it by relative path (when "web" directory is treated as main site directory).

If You want to read about proper way of doing it look:

- [How to include CSS file in Symfony 2 and Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165485/how-to-include-css-file-in-symfony-2-and-twig)
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html