# href assetic doesn't work

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I'm trying to link the stylesheet to an html template, but it doesn't seem to work.

I use symfony2 and assetic. In the demo bundle, the css is linked with the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/css/demo.css') }}" />
```

So, in my mainBundle, I wrote the lines

```
<head>
<style>  
  {% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmemain/css/demo.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />      
  {% endblock %}                               
</style>      
</head>
```

and put my demo.css file in the folder

```
Acme\MainBundle\Resources\public\css,
```

then I executed

```
 php app/console assets:install
```

In this situation, my web page doesn't have css style, it is without formattation. If I write my css directly in my template, it works. But if I link it, it doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

My css file now is only a line:

```
h1{color:blue;text-align:center;}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165485/how-to-include-css-file-in-symfony-2-and-twig

Comment: Did you run `php app/console asset:install`?

Comment: Is your template extended from something? Do you have parent `block stylesheet`?

Comment: @Javad  
Yes, it is extended. But no template extends the block stylesheets. And if I put code in this block, it works, so it is not overwritten.

I tried also to put it out of the   {% block stylesheets %}, so there is not extension problem.

Comment: OK I suggest to get view source of the page and check the path for the stylesheet; then copy that URL and paste in a separate browser and try to download it, if did not work try to change it manually to find what's exact correct address then apply it to the your code

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute this command to copy your stylesheets (found in the public folder) in your web folder
because `asset()` function looking sheets in this folder

```
  php app/console asset:install
```

Look at the [doc](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/templating.html) for more explanations

Comment: I do it, but it doesn't work. I update and integrate the question.

Comment: What you have in your folder web/bundles/acmedemo/css ?

Comment: the demo.css file, from demo bundle.