# Can't load css file

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the same problem as the guy who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165485/how-to-include-css-file-in-symfony-2-and-twig) but since i use symfony 4, it can't be because of not specifying the bundle.

At first, i was trying to load a css file in my template without assetic, using :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/layer.css" />
```

I thought it was enought since that's what the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig) says, but the css is not loading and i have an html file (not actually displayed) instead.

The html file is a symfony error page saying :

> No route found for "GET /css/layer.css"

At first i thought it may be a domain error, so i specified it :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8000/css/layer.css" />
```

but nothing changed.

I also tried to load the css with assetic, using :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/layer.css') }}" />
```

but i got the exact same error. (assetic builded the same route)

The file is : `/css/layer.css`.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Can you help ?

Comment: Do you have a file called /myproject/public/css/layer.css?  Sort of guessing not.

Comment: adding it solved it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using the asset, you need to copy the assets to the web folder with the command `assets:install`

like you see [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command):

> The assets:install command is one of the trickiest things for Symfony
>   newcomers. This command is used to install the web assets (CSS,
>   JavaScript, images) for the production application. When executed
>   without options, the command copies into web/ all the files found in
>   the Resources/public/ directories of your application and bundles.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layer.css">
```

Try this one.Remove the '/' in your path and store the html file and css folder in a common folder.

Comment: Doesn't work either. It seems that the css files must be in the public directory as Cerad told